# Returning values with search or find command in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a problem that I cannot solve.  I am using data from two Excel sheets.  One sheet has a 5 digit number, the other has the same number with a prefix.  Example:

```
Sheet 1     Sheet 2
CT12345     12345
PE23456     23456
```

The numbers are not lined up and sheet 2 contains other data that is not used.  I need to be able to search sheet 1 (entire column) for the proper prefix to assign to the number on sheet 2.  I can have the data placed in an adjacent cell if needed.  I just need that prefix added to the number on sheet 2.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately MATCH allows wildcards. Please try:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH("??"&A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I could not stand it so I dug and played until I came up with this formula that works.                                                                   

=IF(Q37<>"",INDEX(O:O,MATCH("*"&Q37&"*",O:O,0)),"")

Do you know how to display nothing instead of #N/A when there is no match found ?